# Change default page in ASP.NET Core Razor Page from Index to Home

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am changing Default Page

```
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    //...
}).AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Home", "");
});
```

but an exception occured

```
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
/Home
/Index
```

What can I do?

Comment: Try  `options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Home/Index", "");`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One option is to edit the `@page` directive in the `Index.cshtml` and `Home.cshtml` files to [configure the routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages#custom-routes):

```
/* Home.cshtml.cs */
@page "/"
```

```
/* Index.cshtml.cs */
@page "/Index"
```

This applies explicit routes for the two pages, so that the `Home` Razor Pages page becomes the root page, and the `Index` page maps only to `/Index`.

---

Note that with this approach, the call to `AddPageRoute` shown in your question is not needed.